# How to Use Enum in switch case for comparing string- C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have one enum like below

```
public enum Colors
{
    red,
    blue,
    green,
    yellow
}
```

I want to use it switch case

```
public void ColorInfo(string colorName)
{
    switch (colorName)
    {
        // i need a checking like (colorname=="red")
        case Colors.red:
            Console.log("red color");
            break;
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Color' to string
```

Can anyone help on this ..

Comment: Try `switch ((Colors)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorName))`

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet in my opinion is to try to parse the `string` value you get as an input as a `Colors` value, then you can do the `switch` based on the enum only. You can do so by using the [`Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```cs
public void ColorInfo(string colorName)
{
    Colors tryParseResult;
    if (Enum.TryParse<Colors>(colorName, out tryParseResult))
    {
        // the string value could be parsed into a valid Colors value
        switch (tryParseResult)
        {
            // i need a checking like (colorname=="red")
            case Colors.red:
                Console.log("red color");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // the string value you got is not a valid enum value
        // handle as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: So verbose for such a trivial concept. Not one of my favourite things about csharp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare an `enum` to a `string` as they are different types.

If you want to compare a `string` to an `enum` description, then you need to convert it a string first:

```
public void ColorInfo(string colorName)
{
    if (Colors.red.ToString() == colorName)
        Debug.Print("red color");
}
```

You can't use a `switch` statement to do the string conversion as each `case` must be a constant and `Colors.red.ToString()` is not.

An alternative is to convert the string to an `enum` first and then a `switch` statement to compare.

```
public void ColorInfo(string colorName)
{
    try
    {
        Colors color = (Colors)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorName);
        switch (color)
        {
            case Colors.red:
                Debug.Print("red color");
                break;
        }
    }
    catch(ArgumentException ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("Unknown color");
    }
}
```

Comment: the `Enum.Parse` function will throw an exception is the value `colorName` can't be parsed into a `Colors`.

Comment: after googling,using same approach we can use Enum.TryParse..right??

Comment: of course you can, that's what my answer uses. I just wanted to point out that using that code might result in an unexpected exception being thrown since it's not surrounded by a `try`/`catch`.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey good point... I've updated to use try/catch block as an alternative or you can use Enum.TryParse().